# Folders in Applications not in sync with Launchpad

Tags: finder, folders, launchpad

I created a folder in **/Applications** to move all Games into a folder called Games. **Launchpad** is not in sync with the folders that I created.

Looking at the folder **Utilities**, I was under the impression that creating a folder in **/Applications** would keep **Launchpad** in sync .

Is there a way to keep these two distinct Applications (LaunchPad and Finder) which show me a list apps to respect the folders hierarchy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two hierarchies are separate, and cannot be kept in sync without third-party intervention. Even then, there would be difficulties. Note that Launchpad folders have capacity limits that actual folders do not have, and folders within /Applications can contain nested folders, while Launchpad folders cannot.

It's just a coincidence that the apps in /Applications/Utilities match up with the Utilities folder in Launchpad. On my machine, I moved Terminal out of the Utilities folder in Launchpad, but it's still /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app